# Firefox SDK page-mod not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have installed the following extensions: [EPUBReader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/) and [Google Translator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-translator/?src=search). The latter is built using Firefox SDK and originally has a `page-mod include: ["*"]` so it works only on http and https URLs. I modified the line into `include: ["*","file://*","about:*"]` so that it can also work with local files and "about:" links.

The reason i added `"about:*"` is because i want this extension to words on epub books that i read with EPUBReader. EPUBReader produces a URL something like this "about:epubreader?id=5". The problem is, Google Translator still won't translate anything when i double click on the words. It is interesting because whenever i try and open a fake "about:" URL that looks like "about:whatever", it works. I mean, you can double click on any word in the error page and it will translate.

I am pasting here the page-mod code snippet:

```
var workers = [], content_script_arr = [];
pageMod.PageMod({ /* page */
  include: ["*","file://*","about:*"],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("content_script/inject.js")],
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentStyleFile : data.url("content_script/inject.css"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    array.add(workers, worker);
    worker.on('pageshow', function() { array.add(workers, this); });
    worker.on('pagehide', function() { array.remove(workers, this); });
    worker.on('detach', function() { array.remove(workers, this); });
    content_script_arr.forEach(function (arr) {
      worker.port.on(arr[0], arr[1]);
    });
  }
});
```

Help anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with

```
include: /.*/,
```

which adds the `page-mod` to every single URL, and see if the culprit is in the `include`. If that fixed the problem, you can narrow it down even further.

It should fix the problem, because `"*"` only matches `http`, `ftp` and `https` URLS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern#Wildcards.

But maybe the `inject.js` file needs to be included in a publicly-accessible URL, which then gets sent to the translator...